# Converter numeros normais em data

Tags: php, data

Gostaria de saber, se há como converter número normais para formato em data no PHP.

> Exemplo, um usuário digita 09012001 em um `input` do tipo text e o valor retornado em um `echo` mais abaixo seja 09/01/2001

Isso é possivel em `PHP`? se sim, qual seria a maneira mais pratica de se realizar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim, basicamente como deve ser uma **data**, utilize [date_create_from_format](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php) para criar uma um objeto do tipo [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.createfromformat.php) se os dados forem válidos se não retorna `bool(false)` para dados inválidos, **exemplo**:

```
$data = date_create_from_format('dmY', '09012001');
if ($data) // se for data válida
{ 
    echo $data->format('d/m/Y');
}
```

Comment: Deu certo, vlw mano!